# How to get styles of bootstrap's col and row without importing everything?

Tags: css, reactjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-4

I'm making a react app with [styled-components](https://styled-components.com/) and I want to create a component that will be just like using `col col-x` and another for `row` classes from bootstrap.

But my problem is that I can't find the styles for that, I searched for every `.col` word in the repo and couldn't find anything.

How can I make a component using styled-components that recreates bootstrap `col col-x` and `row` without importing the entire bootstrap?

Comment: which version of bootstrap

Comment: @aXuser264 version 4, I added in the tag of my question

Comment: oops!!, AND another thing, did you mean only the `col-x` class or all alikes

Comment: @aXuser264 `col-x` means all classes from `col-1` to `col-12`

Answer (score 1):

You should be able to get it from the Bootstrap CDN https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.0/css/bootstrap.css.

Answer (score 0):

I usually approach this kind of issue by creating a page where I load the library I try to partially emulate and apply it to the structure that I will intend to have. I will extract CSS rules from the dev tools (after loading it in several browsers to find differences of use-cases) and create the same CSS rules into another page, having the same structure, but not using the other library, which is Bootstrap in this case. If there are non-CSS differences, that is, the way that structure is rendered is partially managed by Javascript, then I will make a list of things to achieve and try and find the code for that. In general this will reduce the list of things I have to implement to have only a few items, which tends to be doable.